# strpos not working properly

Tags: php, sql, arrays, string

I am making a website and one thing we need is to get user's interests to show them the best content. User's interests are stored in a table 'Users' in field 'interests'.

Now, the articles are tagged with different interests and one which matches user's interests are shown. Articles are saved in tagged table. So we get the tags of all the articles and then select the interests of users. If an interest is found in the article, then the code echoes true, else it echoes false.

```
$select = "SELECT * from users where username='$username'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $interests = explode(",",$result['interests'],40);
    foreach($interests as $interest) {

        $select1 = "SELECT * from tagged";
        $query1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $select1) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        while ($result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
            echo "Interests:".$interest."<br>";
            echo "Tags:".$result1['tags']."<br>";
            $pos = strpos($result1['tags'], $interest);
            if ($pos===true) {
                echo "Result:true<br>";
            } else {
                echo "Result:false<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The interests list is actually comma-separated so I extract it and explode it into an array and then find the position of the array element in the tags of articles using `strpos()` function. But all the results are showing `true`, even if they are `false`.

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwszk.png)  looks like this.

Comment: Does `strpos()` return `true` ? Read the manual carefully.

Comment: It does not return true.But it does return false..Nd if I reverse it..I will get true.Not like that?

Comment: Strpos returns the number of characters from the starting position of usually 0 that your string matched. Using $pos!==false is equivalent to $pos not 0... meaning not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string. Otherwise, FALSE if the needle was not found:

```
if ($pos!==false) {
    echo "Result:true<br>";
} else {
    echo "Result:false<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `stripos()`

The `stripos()` function finds the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string.

Returns the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string, or FALSE if the string is not found. Note: String positions start at 0, and not 1.

Note: The stripos() function is case-insensitive.

and if condition should be something like this

```
    if ($pos!==false) {
        ..............
    } else {
        ..............
    }
```